# How do I restore the Application Launch Bar in Desktop GUI (LXDE)?

Tags: raspbian, gui, lxde

I wanted to remove Wolfram Language from the taskbar application launcher in Raspbian GUI, but accidentally clicked something that removed the whole panel.

How do I bring it back?

[image]

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

Comment: The default GUI desktop environment (DE) on Raspbian, via which things like taskbars are configured, is [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) and you will have more luck searching/researching about it under that name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right click the Task bar.
2. Select *Add / Remove Panel Items*.
3. Press *Add* and select *Application Launch Bar* from the menu. Click *Add*.
4. Select the newly added *Application Launch Bar* from the list, and click *Preferences*.
5. Add the applications you wish to appear in the *Application Launch Bar*.
6. Reorder the location of the *Application Launch Bar* in the list, by clicking *Up/Down*.
7. Press OK to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

I was also able to restore my panel from the commandline on raspbian stretch:

```
rm -r ~/.config/lxpanel
sudo service lightdm restart
```